# C++ store template parameter as variable

Tags: c++, class, templates, generics

I'm writing a generic wrapper class for a bunch of classes we have defined in other code. I'm trying to figure out if there is a way in C++ to write a templated class that can store a template parameter as a variable. Here is an example of what I would like to see work:

```
template < class C > class generic {
    public:
        C obj; // used for custom type processing

        template < class T > T other; // <- changeable variable (or something)

        template < class T > setOther() { // Function to change variable
            // code to change variable type, or set type
        }

        void doSomethingWithOther() {
            // do some processing for other, like call
            // specific member function or something
            (((other*)obj)->*SomeGenericMethod)()
        }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    Bar bObj;
    generic<Foo> fObj;
    fObj.setOther<Bar>();
    fObj.doSomethingWithOther();
    return 0;
}
```

I know the above code won't compile for many reasons, but my question is more in regards to functionality. Is there some way that I could store a template parameter as a variable (or use a function or something) that could then be used later as a type specifier? If there is not a standard way, any ideas from the SO community that might lead to my desired results?

Please no Boost or other 3rd party libraries, I'm trying to keep it as "STL" (C99) as possible.

Another idea I had was to use default specializations:

```
template < class C, class T = void* > class generic {
    public:
        C obj;
        T other;
        // ... more code
}
```

but in that instance, assuming we had the following:

```
class Test1 {
    public:
        generic<Foo> *G1;
        generic<Foo, Bar> *G2;
};
```

If I wanted to change the type of G1 later to do some other processing, I could say something like the following:

```
G1 = new generic<Foo, Bar>(); // compile error, different types
```

However, this would result in a compile error since the two types pointed to are of different types (G1 is of type `generic< C >` the other is of type `generic< C, T >` even though template class `T` is defaulted to `void*`.

Sorry for the long post, I am trying to be as clear as possible in my intentions with this code. As well, please feel free to correct me in any of my statements above (long days=less brain activity for me)

Thanks in advance for any help in this matter.

Edit 1:

To clarify, the `other` data member is merely there to show that I would like that member to hold a class type. This is because our code has members of other classes calling instanced member functions. And if I were to make a call to a member function of a different class I will get a compile error.

And unfortunately I cannot use any C++0x features as our embedded compilers are older and do not support the 0x feature set. Otherwise that would be the obvious solution.

I am essentially having to build in a delegate type of system so that instanced classes can call members of other instanced classes from within themselves and that called member function will have the memory space and access to the `this` pointer

Example:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        Delegate other;
}

class Bar {
    public:
        void SomeFunction() {
            std::cout << "hello from Bar::SomeFunction, data = " << data << std::endl;
        }

        int data;
}

int main() {
     Foo F;
     Bar B;
     B.data = 10;
     F.other = Delegate::attach<Bar>(&Bar::SomeFunction, &B);
     // Delegate::attach is defined as 
     // template < class T > Delegate attach(void (T::*fnPtr)(void*), T *obj)
     F.other();
}
```

In the above example `void operator()()` of the `Delegate` class then calls the other members function, via `(*fnPtr)()`. If called this way, the function has no access to it's member data (no knowledge of the `this` pointer). If called passing the referenced object (i.e. `(*fnPtr)(obj)`), the function now has access to the member data.

I'm trying to solve this via specifying a generic `class type` object that could then be casted back and forth as the `Delegate other` may attach to any member.

Comment: What would `other` be dependent on to determine what it is?

Comment: ¤ "Please no Boost or other 3rd party libraries" is self-defeating. You don't want to reinvent that wheel yet again, so use boost::any or boost::variant (I forget which is which). Or use that source code as a starting point, although it's unlikely that you can improve it: the modifications to make it non-boost will just degrade the quality. Anyway, why on Earth do you want this? It really does look like **you're asking about an envisioned solution** to some problem, instead of asking about that problem. If so, please ask about the problem. Cheers & hth.,

Comment: "keep as STL as possible" (I assume you mean the C++ standard library): You know that the standard is influenced by Boost and its authors?

Comment: @pmr it's not who designed the standard library or who influenced it, it's that you have to redistribute (or hope the recipient has already has) the large boost library - after learning it and successfully compiling it, etc. That, for some people (myself included) is too much pain and not enough gain.

Comment: @Seth, I agree with portability it's why I'm trying to steer away from 3rd party libraries. Though I'm not trying to reinvent the wheel, it is a company requirement to be as portable as possible with our code base. It's generic SDK for some of our embedded products and unfortunately requires a lot of 'reinventing-the-wheel' due to some of the platforms we need to work on (weird compile environments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what the problem is that you are trying to solve.  In your code, what is the purpose of `class C`?  Anyway, here's a guess at what you want.  Use an underlying template class `implementation` that derives from a common base class with a virtual `interface`, and have the `generic` class hold a pointer to that `interface`.

```
class generic {
    class interface {
    public:
        virtual ~interface(){}
        virtual void SomeGenericMethod()=0;
    };
    template <class T>
    class implementation: public interface {
        T data;
    public:
        implementation(const T& d) :data(d) {}
        virtual void SomeGenericMethod() 
        {return data.SomeGenericMethod();}
    };
    public:
        std::unique_ptr<interface> data;

        template < class T > void setOther(const T& other) {
            data.reset(new implementation<T>(other));
        }

        void doSomethingWithOther() {
            data->SomeGenericMethod();
        }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    generic fObj;
    Bar bObj;
    fObj.setOther(bObj);
    fObj.doSomethingWithOther();
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/A1Aqu

Comment: Hi, the `class C` is part of the signature I have in the code I'm using now, it's used in other parts of the generic class, not really important to the outcome of the problem, sorry for not clarifying that. Anyways, thanks for reply and tip, I'll try out a variation of your suggestion as I think it might get me on the right track

Comment: Good news is I was just informed I can now implement C++0x, and the virtual interface trick ended up accomplishing the goal of what I was trying to do...thanks!

Comment: @txtechhelp: Glad I could help!  `unique_ptr` isn't key to the answer, it simply prevents mistakes.

Comment: @txtechhelp: Also note this is all _significantly_ easier if the objects in question derive from common virtual interfaces to begin with.

Comment: Aggree with the unique_ptr, it is very handy and it certainly makes my life easier, also, the main reason I went with this answer is because all of the objects we will be passing around are in fact all derived from a pure virtual 'interface' class we use for alot of data types. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @txtechhelp: If they all derive from a virtual interface, why do you need the generic object at all?  Can't you just hold a `interface*`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the exact type at compile time, you cannot encode it as template parameter. Those must be known at compile-time and cannot be changed after that. Check out `Boost.Any` (any possible type) or `Boost.Variant` (multiple known types) for examples that can help you. `any` is implementable with reasonable effort, `variant` not so much. Given your knowledge about C++ templates you might should not attempt to implement either without really understanding the code in boost, no offense intended.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will look into how the Boost library implements its variant types and see if they can help. Unfortunately due to strict coding enforcements, I can't bring on any 3rd party libraries, otherwise this would all be moot, lol.

Comment: But please don't try to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your main goal is to call some member function of `other`.

If that is the case, you don't even need `other`, but just a functor that encapsulates the call. E.g. with C++11 or TR1:

```
template <class C> struct A {
    C obj;
    std::function<void ()> op;
    void f() {
        // ...
        op();
    }
};

struct B {
    void g() { std::cout << "moo" << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
    A<int> a;
    B b;
    a.op = std::bind(&B::g, &b);
    a.f();
}
```

Comment: Hi Georg, thanks for the info, unfortunately I cannot use any C++0x features that would be helpful to my current situation (no compiler support). Though I do like the idea because of its simplicity, I essentially would want to emulate this functionality in my code, back to Google ..

Comment: @txt: Maybe look into [fast delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/FastDelegate.aspx) or extracting just `boost::function` & `boost::bind` using [bcp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/tools/bcp/doc/html/index.html)?